# Page curl css3 effect issue

Tags: css

http://www.triniscene.com/tsv7/caribbean/galleries/

Can anyone point out what is causing the page curl effect to NOT be visible. I'm wrecking my brain here and I'm just not figuring it out

Comment: What did u mean by curl effect?

Comment: the shadow you get when you do this http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-paper-curls/ for some reason i don't get the :after shadow

Comment: Where do you want this shadow curl effect on your website, can you be more specific and provide some screenshots / fiddle or something?

Comment: sorry here is a sample sinppet

http://jsfiddle.net/ADyzq/

If you look at the sample the CSS and html works. But for the life of me i can't figure out why it doesn't work on the website...does it have something to do with the fact that the content is dynamic? I doubt it but I'm stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I figured it out which was pretty weird imo. Originally I thought the issue lied within my css markup but after noticing how it worked in Fiddle and not on the website I did some more digging. turns out when you made the :after z-index:-1 the stacking order went behind the parent divs which I just realized was position:relative. giving the parent div a z-index fixed it.

Weird